# Как изменить ориентацию устройства в горизонтальное положение при запуске кода в PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Мне нужно при запуске кода в PyQt5 изменить ориентацию (с вертикальной в горизонтальную), проще говоря активировать поворот экрана, мой код:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.Qt import *
MyApp = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
V = MyApp.desktop().screenGeometry()
h = V.height()
w = V.width()
try:
    from PyQt5.QtWinExtras import QtWin
    myappid = 'mycompany.myproduct.subproduct.version'
    QtWin.setCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID(myappid)
except ImportError:
    pass
class StartWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = StartWindow()
    ex.setWindowTitle('MyApp')
    ex.showFullScreen()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Вот пример, как я хочу это реализовать: [image]

Код, что я привел просто создаёт окно, дабы вам было легче взять код и продолжить работу. Я хотел сделать простенькую игру на телефоны, для этого и нужно было повернуть экран, потому что в вертикальном положении не очень удобно было бы играть

Comment: То, что вы привели в качестве примера - это что? Как можно понять что вы отображаете? Где можно посмотреть что вы хотите получить? Исправьте ваш вопрос и ради любопытства - что это будет и для чего вы это хотите сделать.

Comment: Обновил вопрос, добавил картинку, объяснение кода и для чего мне это нужно

Comment: https://forum.qt.io/topic/66240/how-to-detect-rotate-on-android/2

Comment: к сожалению, тот язык программирования, что используется там мне не подходит(

Answer (score 0):

С мобильной разработкой не сталкивался, но подозреваю, что надо оставить из доступных ориентаций только landscape

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.primaryScreen().setOrientationUpdateMask(QtCore.Qt.LandscapeOrientation)
```

Comment: Попробовал, не помогло(

Comment: А как деплоили на ведроид? Ориентацию же на сколько я знаю можно прописать в манифесте

Comment: пробовал программой PyDroid, питон на ваш способ не реагирует, если есть другой, то напишите, пожалуйста